# Convert indexed DB table rows to JSON Array in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, indexeddb, dexie

I have list of values in an indexed DB table. I just want to convert into JSON array. My indexed DB table structure is given below.

[image]

I am using dexie framework for indexed DB .

```
db.booking.each(function(obj) {     
    var re_data = JSON.stringify(obj);
})
```

If I print `re_data` it displays like this:

```
{
    "booking_id": "18486",
    "restbooking_id": "INBNGU18457",
    "guest_id": 55648
},{
    "booking_id": "18487",
    "restbooking_id": "INBNGU18458",
    "guest_id": 53726
},{
    "booking_id": "18488",
    "restbooking_id": "INBNGU18459",
    "guest_id": 53537
}
```

My desired output need in JSON ARRAY like following ,

```
"bookings": [{ 
    "booking_id": "18486",
    "restbooking_id": "INBNGU18457",
    "guest_id": 55648
},{
    "booking_id": "18487",
    "restbooking_id": "INBNGU18458",
    "guest_id": 53726
},{
    "booking_id": "18488",
    "restbooking_id": "INBNGU18459",
    "guest_id": 53537
}]
```

Or can I do this using the dexie framework itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer :
instead of db.booking.each() i used db.booking.toArray().

So Code is :

```
     db.restaurantbooking.toArray(callfunc);

      function callfunc(v)
    {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(v)); // This produce JSON Array.

    }
```

My desired output is displayed.